# How to update the text selection release from window

Tags: jquery

Using user mouse selection, i am getting the `selected` text, and updating to a container. when user click out (selection released), i would like to update the `selected` text as empty.

i tried this way, but  seem not working properly,

```
    $('#tenderContent').on('mouseup', '.tenderdocument', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($.trim(window.getSelection().toString()).length) {
       $('#text').text(window.getSelection().toString());
    }
});

$('#tenderContent').on('click', '.tenderdocument', function () {
    var selection = $.trim(window.getSelection().toString());
    if(!selection) {
        console.log("there is no selection"); //nothing consoles after selection released
        $.event.trigger({type:'textUnselected'});
    }
});
```

[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/mx09jcay/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `if` condition that checks for a selection before updating:

```
$('#tenderContent').on('mouseup', '.tenderdocument', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#text').text(window.getSelection().toString());
});
```

**Update**

If you want to run a specific function when the selection is cleared, try this:

```
$('#tenderContent').on('mouseup', '.tenderdocument', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($.trim(window.getSelection().toString()).length) {
        $('#text').text(window.getSelection().toString());
    }
    else {
        $('#text').empty();
        console.log("there is no selection"); //nothing consoles after selection released
        $.event.trigger({ type:'textUnselected' });
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/mx09jcay/4/)

Comment: No, I require to `flag(trigger)` the `false` in case there is no selected `text` length. in sample work i am not noted

Comment: That's not what your logic is doing.

Comment: Also, note that `$.event.trigger()` is pointless as you're not supplying an element to raise/trap the event against.

Answer (score 1):

You only watch for clicks on the `.tenderdocument` element inside the `#tendercontent`, if the click happens outside of that you won't get noticed.

Try to bind on the document level to catch all clicks, like this:

```
$('#tenderContent').on('mouseup', '.tenderdocument', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($.trim(window.getSelection().toString()).length) {
       $('#text').text(window.getSelection().toString());
    }
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var selection = $.trim(window.getSelection().toString());
    if(!selection && !$('#text').is(':empty')) {
        $('#text').empty();
        alert('text emptied!');
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hdaj1t7w/3/

Comment: Yes, agree. is their a way to protect the `click` on `mouseup`, even a first time i am getting the trigger

Comment: updated my answer, now it checks that something has been selected beforehand.